# when to use Dependency Property in WP7 / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

What is the speciality of Dependency property in Silverlight. I searched many sites but i won’t get a clear cut idea about this. Can any one let me know in what context  this dependency property can be used in Silverlight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the simple rule of thumb.  If you are creating a control (either a UserControl or a Custom templated control) add new properties using Dependency Properties.  Otherwise its rare to create model or view model classes that derived from `DependencyObject` you would just use standard properties perhaps with an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Dependency properties are the basis for data binding.  You can't use data binding on a property which isn't implemented as a `DependencyProperty`.  For similar reasons a property needs to be implemented as `DependencyPropertry` if it is to be animated using `Storyboard` animations.

Comment: Hi Anthony. is there any direct relation b/w attached properties and DependencyProperty? In what sence they differ??

Comment: @Stephan: Yes there is a direct relation they are very similar things.  Most of the time a dependency property is assigned to the class its declared.  Whereas an __attached__ propery is specifically designed to be attached to an instance of another type rather than the one its declared in. This allows for additional functionality to be grafted on to an object that is completely unware of the new functionality.  E.g. `Canvas.Left` allows a containing canvas to postion an `UIElement`, the `UIEement` itself knows nothing of this.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Last time I submit before going to lunch.. and leave out the revisions :(

Answer (score 0):

When you create a UserControl.  If your property is a normal public property like that :

```
public Double MyProperty
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

1. You won't be able to apply styling to the property.
2. You won't be able to apply an animation based on that property in Storyboards.

Comment: Regarding point 1, I think you will be able to set the property, but you won't be able to set it to a `{Binding}` - only to a static value